# Is there a better way to loop over 6 layers of JSON objects and multiple nested arrays values, with nested objects inside them?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, nested

I am very new in dealing with API's using PHP. Simple API returns I'm ok with handling. This one however has like layers and layers of complexity that is beyond my skillet. I managed to write some likely WAY overkill code to deal with just printing to the screen all values. I like to do this when I learn so I can see the results of what I think is happening to verify and to see errors as I move along.

In reality, all I really need is 2 values from this mess; the LAT & LONG for the address I am checking.

Is there not a better way to pick the following values out?:

- LAT = $data['results']['locations'][latLng].{lat:39.78373}
- LONG = $data['results']['locations'][latLng].{lng:-100.445882}

**I'd rather not loop like this below, just to set 2 variables in the middle**

---

```
<?PHP
$data = json_decode('{"info":{"statuscode":0,"copyright":{"text":"\u00A9 2019 MapQuest, Inc.","imageUrl":"http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif","imageAltText":"\u00A9 2019 MapQuest, Inc."},"messages":[]},"options":{"maxResults":-1,"thumbMaps":true,"ignoreLatLngInput":false},"results":[{"providedLocation":{"location":"2032 Hopkins Mill Rd,Roswell 30077,GA"},"locations":[{"street":"","adminArea6":"","adminArea6Type":"Neighborhood","adminArea5":"","adminArea5Type":"City","adminArea4":"","adminArea4Type":"County","adminArea3":"","adminArea3Type":"State","adminArea1":"US","adminArea1Type":"Country","postalCode":"","geocodeQualityCode":"A1XXX","geocodeQuality":"COUNTRY","dragPoint":false,"sideOfStreet":"N","linkId":"0","unknownInput":"","type":"s","latLng":{"lat":39.78373,"lng":-100.445882},"displayLatLng":{"lat":39.78373,"lng":-100.445882},"mapUrl":"http://open.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v5/map?key=123456&type=map&size=225,160&locations=39.7837304,-100.4458825|marker-sm-50318A-1&scalebar=true&zoom=2&rand=-1073424276"}]}]}',true);

    foreach($data as $key => $child) {
        if(is_array($child)){
            foreach($child as $keya => $a){
                if(is_array($a)){
                    foreach ($a as $keyb =>$b) {
                        if(is_array($b)){
                            foreach($b as $keyc => $c){
                                if(is_array($c)){
                                    foreach($c as $keyd =>$d){
                                        if(is_array($d)){
                                            foreach($d as $keye =>$e){
                                                echo "<b>". $keye . "</b> : " . $e . '</br>';
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            echo "<b>". $keyd . "</b> : " . $d . '</br>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    echo "<b>". $keyc . "</b> : " . $c . '</br>';
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "<b>". $keyb . "</b> : " . $b . "</br>";
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<b>". $keya . "</b> : " . $a . "</br>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "<b>". $key . "</b> : " . $child . "</br>";
        }
     }
?>
```

Comment: Why not just `$data['results']['locations']['latLng']['lat'] = '39.78373';` ?

Comment: You don't have to loop. `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($data); echo '</pre>';` will tell you the path to your data.

Comment: If the "layers" are always the same just extract them directly using something like `$lat = ['results']['locations']['latLng']['lat'];`.

Comment: Will there be more than 1 `providedLocation` and/or more than one returned `locations`?

Comment: @Alex I don't know the value in the actual usage this was one JSON response - going in I had no clue what the value was

Comment: @MonkeyZuse  - the actual use is not to dump the array to screen only, but an exercise to get to what I want (LAT LONG VALUES).

Comment: @Dave they seam to be the same according to the API Docs but this code <<echo $data['results']['locations']['latLng']['lat'];>> produces the error "Notice: Undefined index: locations in xxx.php on line x" and why I did the above to see where the value actually is

Comment: @AbraCadaver  - no always a 1 to 1 call https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/open/geocoding-api/address/get/

Comment: `echo $data['results'][0]['locations'][0]['latLng']['lat'];` Just look at the nesting https://3v4l.org/jsqeK If there are more than 1 `results` or `locations` then you need to loop those.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - this works as I need, I was not including the [0] nor did I realize it was there like that I was using https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com that did not show it like you provided - TOTALLY bookmarking 3v4l.org - THANKS!!!